# JavaScript and JQuery: Displaying Time in Text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to display time only in the text field in HTML using JavaScript but its not showing. Kindly help me out.

```
<input type="text" name="time1" id="e1" value="" />

<script>
function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
var x1=x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getYear(); 
x1 = x1 + " - " +  x.getHours( )+ ":" +  x.getMinutes() + ":" +  x.getSeconds();
//document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x1;
//tt=display_c();
document.getElementById('e1').value = x1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: Works fine if you call the function: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uyrLg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call your function.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="time1" id="e1" value="" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function display_ct() {
    var strcount
    var x = new Date()
    var x1=x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getYear(); 
    x1 = x1 + " - " +  x.getHours( )+ ":" +  x.getMinutes() + ":" +  x.getSeconds();
    //document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x1;

    //tt=display_c();
    document.getElementById('e1').value = x1;
}

display_ct();
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/aGGHQ/

Comment: Yes, you just have to call the function from the `window.onload` event handler. See this updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aGGHQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

`getYear` is no longer used and has been replaced by the `getFullYear` method.

```
var x1=x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getFullYear();
```